# How to call on a large amount of data without burdening the server

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Because I need to download 140k members up from a database, I have chosen to call 1000medlemmer at a time in a loop, otherwise it will overload the server.

The aim is to collect 140k and display them in a CSV format.

My problem now is that the loop does not really work. It retrieves members, but it picks up multiple times the same members. I can not really see if there is something wrong with my loop? It must be said that there are unique members of the DB.

This is my code

```
$development = array(
    'testing' => false,
    'testing_loops' => 1,
);

$settings = array(
   'times_looped' => 0,
    'members_at_a_time' => 1000,
        'print_settings' => true,
    'members_looped' => 0);


function outputCSV($data) 
    {

    $outstream = fopen("php://output", 'w');

    array_walk($data, '__outputCSV', $outstream);

    fclose($outstream);
    }

function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) 
    {
        fwrite($filehandler, implode(',',$vals). "\n");
    }


function getMembers($settings, $ee){

    // SQL FROM
    $sql_from = $settings['times_looped'] * $settings['members_at_a_time'];

    // SQL LIMIT
    $sql_limit = $sql_from . ', ' . $settings['members_at_a_time'];

    // GET MEMBERS
    $query = $ee->EE->db->query("SELECT m.email,
    cr.near_rest_1_id, cr.near_rest_1_distance, 
    cr.near_rest_2_id, cr.near_rest_2_distance,
    cr.near_rest_3_id, cr.near_rest_3_distance
    from exp_members m
    left join 
    exp_menucard_closest_restaurants cr
    on m.member_id = cr.member_id
    where group_id = 8 and 14 limit ".$sql_limit."");

    // Check if members found
    if($query->num_rows() == 0){
        return $query->num_rows();
    }

    // Update number of members
    $settings['members_looped'] = $settings['members_looped'] + $query->num_rows();

    // Loop members
    foreach($query->result_array() as $row) {

       if($row['near_rest_1_distance'] > 1.0)
        {$near_rest_1_distance= number_format($row['near_rest_1_distance'], 2, ',', ',') ." ". 'km';}

        else
        {$near_rest_1_distance= number_format($row['near_rest_1_distance'], 3, ',', '')*1000 ." ". 'meter';}

        if($row['near_rest_2_distance'] > 1.0)
        {$near_rest_2_distance= number_format($row['near_rest_2_distance'], 2, ',', ',') ." ". 'km';}

        else
        {$near_rest_2_distance= number_format($row['near_rest_2_distance'], 3, ',', '')*1000 ." ". 'meter';}

        if($row['near_rest_3_distance'] > 1.0)
        {$near_rest_3_distance= number_format($row['near_rest_3_distance'], 2, ',', ',') ." ". 'km';}

        else
        {$near_rest_3_distance= number_format($row['near_rest_3_distance'], 3, ',', '')*1000 ." ". 'meter';}

         $nearest_rest_result_array[] = array(
        'email' =>  $row['email'],
        'near_rest_1_id' =>  $row['near_rest_1_id'],
        'near_rest_1_distance' => $near_rest_1_distance,
        'near_rest_2_id' =>  $row['near_rest_2_id'],
        'near_rest_2_distance' =>  $near_rest_2_distance, 
        'near_rest_3_id' => $row['near_rest_3_id'],
        'near_rest_3_distance' =>  $near_rest_3_distance
        ); 

        // Write to CSV
    outputCSV($nearest_rest_result_array);
    }

    // Loop again
    return $query->num_rows();
}


// Loop
$more_rows = true;
while($more_rows == true || $more_rows > 0) {
    // Test
    if($settings['times_looped'] >= $development['testing_loops'] && $development['testing'] == true){
        break;
    }
    // get members
    $more_rows = getMembers($settings, $this);
    $settings['members_looped'] = $settings['members_looped'] + $more_rows;
    $settings['times_looped']++;

    if($settings['members_looped'] < $settings['members_at_a_time']){
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the point of this code?  Are you trying to render the list somewhere? Are you doing some kind of batch process to update some value on each member?  I ask because it seems like something that you'd want to handle by a batch process asynchronously

Comment: Meaning of the code is to create a CSV format output. I am not trying to update anything, just to show the array of 140k members that I get from DB

Comment: To weed out duplicates, you can use their email as the key `$nearest_rest_result_array[$row['email']]` and put the array assignment in `if( !array_key_exists( $row['email'], $nearest_rest_result_array ) ) {`. This will prevent your script from adding a record where the e-mail is the same. Your sql should have joined them by member_id so you shouldn't be getting any duplicate member_ids